# How can I display a counter in html?

Tags: html, counter

I would like my webpage (HTML) to contain something like this:

"In setting 10, we did ...,
in setting 9, we did ... "

I would like the numbers to be counted automatically (say, from x to 1; the number x will be manually supplied in the beginning of the html code), because I rearrange these items every day, and I would like them to automatically adjust.

So I think it should be something like counter-decrement, but I do not know how to display them.

I am not using a list environment, since I need these numbers to appear in the plain text.

Any ideas how this can be done? Thank you.

Comment: There is this thing called javascript, you might wanna check it out.

Comment: You might want to check questions with the [tag:css-counter] tag.